# Unable to receive copy of sales order email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales

I am having a problem receiving copies of order emails.

I have configured Mage to as follows:
System | Configuration | Sales |Sales Emails
Enabled = Yes
...
Send Order Email Copy To: my email address
Send Order Email Copy Method: Separate Email (but it also does not work for Bcc)

The Order Confirmation successfully sends to the person who placed the order, but the copy is never sent (as far as I can tell).

My email is configured to send via localhost:25. I beleive this is working because the buyer gets the order confirmation.

Is the order confirmation, and the copy, both sent the same way? Some people say the copy is sent by scheduled cron. I installed AOE_Scheduler and it says the cron jobs are running fine.

Can you help me troubleshoot why the order copy email is not being generated/sent? If it is related to Cron, how can I check that the cron job is running in order to send the queue?

Comment: To check your cron is working you can go into the admin under the AOE Scheduler and it should say last heart beat if it says x minutes ago its working fine if it says no heartbeat then go into your cpanel and go to crons under this section you can add you email to check that is being run. which should give you an idea if its working or not if not check your command for running the cron is correct and let it run again. if all is well then your emails should start filtering through.

Answer (score 0):

As you say if you have well checked the cron, check now this if it looks like this:

**app/code/code/Mage/Core/model/Email.php**

```
public function queueOrderUpdateEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '', $forceMode = false)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

        if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendOrderCommentEmail($storeId)) {
            return $this;
        }
        // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
        $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
        $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);
        // Check if at least one recipient is found
        if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
            return $this;
        }

        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }

        /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        if ($notifyCustomer) {
            /** @var $emailInfo Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info */
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
            if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
                // Add bcc to customer email
                foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                    $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
                }
            }
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }

        // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is
        // 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
        if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($email);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }
        }

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'   => $this,
                'comment' => $comment,
                'billing' => $this->getBillingAddress()
            )
        );

        /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
        $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
            ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
            ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_UPDATE_ORDER)
            ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);
        $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();

        return $this;
    }
```